# Nhibernate is supported with .net core 2.1?

Tags: .net, postgresql, nhibernate, .net-core

nhibernate is supported with .net core 2.1?

I try to find tutorial with nhibernate, .net core 2.1 (or 2.0 if 2.1 not work with hib) and postgresql.

Answer (score 2):

Their [NuGet package 5.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate/) says it supports

- .NET Framework 4.6.1
- .NET Core 2.0
- .NET Standard 2.0

So it should work fine with .NET Core 2.1, there is no reason to not make a project, install the package and test it for yourself.